# Can't load an image from a library in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need a library to load an SVG (using the flutter_svg package) located in the main app's assets directory. Right now I have the following code in the library function:

```
SvgPicture.asset(svgSrc, package: 'example_app')
```

Where svgSrc will be 'assets/images/logo.svg'.

However on flutter run I get the following exception:

```
Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/packages/example_app/assets/images/logo.svg" (404)
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
Unable to load asset: packages/example_app/assets/images/logo.svg
```

I have added the main app's pubspec.yaml I have:

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: make sure in pubspec.yaml the `assets:` key sits below the `flutter:` key

Comment: Thanks, it was but my indentation was wrong. Even after correcting it I still get the same exception though.

Comment: then make sure that the file actually sits in this directory `packages/example_app/assets/images/logo.svg` it happened to me once that there was an assets folder inside an assetsfolder and so the path was wrong.

Comment: I've verified that the file is there in the relative path, but "packages" is not there as a parent directory of example_app. Do the library and the app have to share a packages parent directory?

Comment: the path provided under the `assets:` key seems to be relative to your app root directory. I personally put my assets folder next to the lib, build, ... folders inside the root directory of my project.

Comment: Yes, my assets folder is next to lib, build, etc. as well.

Comment: You should show your project directory structure. You definitely have an issue with paths

Comment: The library and the app are in completely different paths. In my app's directory I have the directory assets/images, this is included in pubspec.yaml as assets/images/.

Comment: @Jason So, you want to share assets from your main app to a package?

Comment: Yes, the package needs to render the image.

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure that it's possible. I think you should put that image into the package and share it with the main app from the package then if you need so

Comment: @Yuri That's what I was trying to avoid, because I want to distribute the package. Perhaps the package can be copied to the lib folder of the app if there's no other way.

Comment: @Jason you can always create another package to hold your shared images

Comment: @Yuri Thanks! I'll try that, I think that should work.

Comment: @Yuri That didn't work either.

Comment: @Jason I'll provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](https://github.com/YuriHeiko/flutter_shared_images_example) showing how to share images via a custom package.

in answer to Jason's comment: it's just a question of paths. You can easily move `packages` to any location until you can locate them in your `pubspec.yaml`
f.e. move it to one directory up and change `pubspec.yaml` accordingly:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  images:
    path: ../packages/images/
  another_package:
    path: ../packages/another_package/
```

Comment: In your example the packages are copied directly to the main app. If that is the only way to get it working, then you are correct.